# For a particular datetime, find a record with the closest datetime before and after

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, datetime

Let's have a MySQL database table that contains a DateTime column `when`. Such a column may carry any DateTime value other than NULL.

How can I create a table that would contain columns `when`, `whenA`, and `whenB`, with all full-minute DateTime values (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:00) between the minimum and maximum `when` values and `whenA` being the closest DateTime on or before, and `whenB` being the closest DateTime on or after the `when` value? If the exact `when` value exists, `whenA` and `whenB` would be the same as `when`. If no record on or before, or on or after doesn't exist, NULL will be filled into `whenA` or `whenB`, respectively.

Obviously, there are many possible approaches how to make it, but the question is what should be the most efficient one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the values using a recursive CTE.  Then you can use correlated subqueries to get what you want:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(min(whent)) / 60) * 60) as minw,
         max(whent) as maxw
      from t
      union all
      select minw + interval 1 minute, maxw
      from cte
      where minw < maxw
     )
select minw,
       (select max(t2.when)
        from t t2
        where t2.when = cte.minw
       ) as when,
       (select max(t2.when)
        from t t2
        where t2.when <= cte.minw
       ) as when_before,
       (select min(t2.when)
        from t t2
        where t2.when >= cte.minw
       ) as when_after
from cte;
```

Note that `when` is a really bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword and a reserved word in MySQL.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b732595749651f458b275a887f14f395) is a db<>fiddle.

I should note that if you have a numbers or tally table of some sort, that could also be used.